# What is the real use of decorators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-decorators

### **I'm trying to understand the real world use of decorators.**

coming on the decorators we all know that it is used to decorate the function.
    It means we can add something extra to the existing function but it can be done by using other simple function also we can call one function which will call the other function. So why we need to use the decorators.

I have already tried to make two program

1. **with decorators**

   ```
   def decor_result(result_as_argument):
    def new_function(marks):
        for i in marks:
               if i>= 75:
                   print("Congrats distiction",i)   
          else:
              result_as_argument(marks)
      return new_function

   @decor_result
   def result(marks):
      for i in marks:
          if i >= 35:
              pass
           else:
               print("Fail")
           break
       else:
           print("Pass")   

   result([79,65,55,78,12])
   ```
2. **without decorators**

   ```
   def result_distict(marks):
       for i in marks:
           if i>= 75:
               print("Congrats distiction",i)   
       else:
           result(marks)
   def result(marks):
       for i in marks:
           if i >= 35:
               pass
           else:
               print("Fail")
               break
       else:
           print("Pass")
   result_distict([79,65,55,78,12])
   result([79,65,55,78,12])
   ```

**By doing this I came to know that without using decorators, it is more simplified and we are free to use any of the function what we want and by using decorators we can not use the old function so why and where to use decorators?**

Comment: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: To extend, just a tiny bit; it is about patterns. When you want to do the same extension to several functions, a decorater is only written once, and then applied over and over, whereas the more naive approach requires each function to be wrapped with the same code, i.e., you need to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, doing a decorator is not necessary. You want to use a decorator when you're trying to implement a specific behavior to a set of functions. For instance, let's say you're trying to display the execution time of all the functions in your script.

Solution 1) You add a little piece of code everywhere to display it:

```
from time import time

def f1():
    t0 = time()
    # f1 body
    print("Execution time of f1: {}".format(time()-t0))

def f2():
    t0 = time()
    # f2 body
    print("Execution time of f2: {}".format(time()-t0))
```

As you can see, the code is very repetitive. If you want to change anything in this shared behavior, then you have to modify all the functions. That's where decorator are useful.

2) Using decorators:

```
def timer(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        t0 = time()
        res = func(*args,**kwargs)
        duration = time()-t0

        print("Execution time of {}: {} s".format(func.__name__, duration))
        return res

    return wrapper

@timer
def f1():
    # body of f1

@timer
def f2():
    # body of f2
```